# Django unit tests - API calls slowing down testing greatly, optimize or rewrite?

Tags: django, api, unit-testing

I have an application that calls to OpenWeatherMap API and I decided to write a test for the purpose of verifying that the cities are listed on the url page context.

I used the setUpTestData class method to populate the test DB, but when I run the tests the time taken goes from 0.0XX seconds without the test DB to like 5.7XX seconds with the test DB.

I believe its the API calls to populate the DB that is causing the slow down (Which I assume also counts against my limit for calls per hour on the API key) and I am wondering what the proper way would be to test something like this? I.E something that relies on API data to work properly.

Do I need to optimize my code, or is my approach wrong? I am relatively new to unit testing, so I appreciate any tips or advice you may have.

views.py

```
class WeatherHomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name='weather/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        url = 'API URL'
        cities = City.objects.all()

        weather_data = []

        for city in cities:
            city_weather = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()

            weather = {
                'city' : city,
                'temperature' : city_weather['main']['temp'],
                'description' : city_weather['weather'][0]['description'],
                'icon' : city_weather['weather'][0]['icon'],
            }

            weather_data.append(weather)

        context = {'weather_data' : weather_data}

        return context
```

test_views.py

```
class WeatherViewTests(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        City.objects.create(
            name='denver'
        )
        City.objects.create(
            name='honolulu'
        )
        City.objects.create(
            name='tokyo'
        )
...
    
    def test_home_shows_all_cities(self):
        '''Tests to verify all cities in the DB (3) are listed in the home view.'''
        cities = City.objects.all()
        response = self.client.get(reverse('weather:weather-home'))
        self.assertTrue(len(response.context['weather_data']) == 3)
```

Comment: Your unittests should not be calling any external APIs, make testable functions that take responses from the API and test those with mocked data. If you want to test methods that __have__ to call the API then mock out the request

Comment: as in filling in the weather_data with manual values? I guess that does make more sense lol 
How would that be implemented though to reflect the context of the view?

Answer (score 0):

As the commentator hinted at, you should be to "mocking" these requests.  This is one area that I had a really... *really* hard time with when learning how to test and have never really mastered... so I avoid them whenever possible.  There are *many* opinions on how and when to use this technique; some say **never** mock.  Some say, **mock it all**.  It's a balance of finding what works for you.

However, it is indisputable that you should never call an external API in a test.  How you do so will depend on if you want to test;

**a)** that the request is formatted properly
**b)** if your app handles the response properly.
**c)** WHEN/IF certain methods are called

**Example A**

```
mock = Mock(return_value=None)
mock('foo', bar='baz')
mock.assert_called_once_with('foo', bar='baz')
mock('other', bar='values')
mock.assert_called_once_with('other', bar='values')
```

**Example B**

```
mock = Mock()
mock.return_value = 'fish'
mock()
>> 'fish'
```

**Example C**

```
mock = Mock()
mock.method()

mock.method.assert_called()
```

You can read up more on how to use unittest.mock [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) as these are *very* contrived examples.  If you feel your knowledge is lacking in understanding testing concepts (how/when/why we test) I'd highly suggest reading "[Obey the testing goat](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/)".  I regularly refer to this when I'm having trouble conceiving of a test to write.